# only allow access to url in certain locations (qr codes)

Tags: javascript

My company  has a social networking platform that is accessed via a URL.

We are trying to find a way to advertise our URL in sports stores, with access to our site only possible if you come to the store - we do not want the sharing of the URL to anyone, anywhere.

We have considered QR codes and wonder if it's possible our site can only be accessed when a provided QR code is scanned.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically looking for **keys/ access codes** that give your customers access to a site.

Those might have to be on a per-user basis, as otherwise one might just leak an access code for the whole public to use.

**If sharing keys should be disallowed:**

You need a database (sql) to store your cusstomers' information.

Depending on how you generate a key (dynamically, by a set of rules or randomly, using a catalogue of valid keys) you might need a further table to store the keys separately (in case you choose the more secure option of generating a predefined set of random keys)

You can then include those keys in your QR Codes' target URL like `www.example.com?key=1jh303u` or something similar.
(This means of course that you have to produce customized QR Codes, which in turn means they cannot be  printex as a standard mass-produced offset job, but as a customized digital print - so you'd have to send all the different generated QR Codes to your printer)

Once the user visits this URL containing the query string, your site can then check to see if the key is a) valid (in the table) and b) unused, by taking the `&_GET["key"]` variable and querying the database.
If the key is invalid, output an "access denied" page.
If the key exists but has already been checked in, you can use a user-based login system to handle the login.
If the key is valid and hasn't been used yet, you can output your exclusive content at last.

**If it doesn't matter whether people will be able to share their key**, you don't need a database at all. You could build a keygen which creates keys after a certain destinct pattern, and use that same set of rules to validate against the entered key.

Comment: As you only provided us with so much information, a general answer is all I can give you right now.

Comment: Hi Ben Philipp, Thank you very much for your input. I'm putting your thoughts to a few people involved in the project and i'm sure that will be of great help. I will forward some more details once i've spoken with them. Many thanks